# When should I use type level computation in scala?

Tags: scala, type-level-computation

I have been studying type-level programming in scala lately, and apparently it can do [some fancy stuff](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-4d-peano-arithmetic/) at compile time, and that's interesting and impressive. I am wondering when should I use these tricks (after I get sufficiently familiar with them)?

Admittedly this is a very broad question, but I guess I am not the only one who is thinking about this, so hopefully experts can shed some light for the newbies.

Comment: I believe that when you learn all those tricks, it will become easier for you to answer the question: _is it worth the effort_ ? If you can answer this question, you know whether you should do that. If you can't - you are not yet ready. I believe that's the only answer that can be given. Everything else is too broad for SO. And it's true for any question like "When should I use _<put your fancy technology here>_?"

Answer (score 3):

The golden rule is to do so when it leads you to a safer and more elegant solution that is easy to understand and faster to implement than a regular solution. Otherwise code in the way you prefer or the way you are advised to. It's like asking "when should I use functional style vs imperative style?" Imho it's up to you. Some solutions are more natural with functional and others are more natural with imperative. The same is true for type level programming but what is intrisically easier with type level programming could become a nightmare for someone that is still struggling with the basics.

Also you could find a lot of already developed stuff with this style, like shapeless and many other libs that leverage the power of Scala's type system to solve common problems and support powerful abstractions that maybe you wouldn't look for otherwise.

My suggestion, as someone that is still struggling with type level programming, is to start with tools like shapeless and first learn the abstractions inherited from category theory and all that stuff. When you will have many of these concepts in your bag, you could start thinking of new solutions to implement with the type system.

My 2 cents.